# Go router navigation with splash screen on init and list of pages Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-go-router

I was trying to solve this problem for several days with no luck. I am just extremely confused with go router logic... I am building a little platform. When user opens my web app, it checks the URL path and changes several things like colors and links. It works now, but I still want to use go Router navigation. Here is [working example with no Go router](https://otree.pro/catalogue)

Here is what I am trying to achieve:
[image: I am trying to achieve this]

Basically, I want several points to work, and I know it is a lot to ask, but maybe someone will help me:

1. disable browser back button navigation
2. when user opens my web app with any path, I want the splash screen to be displayed. But when I navigate later it should not.
   3.Shell route that works only after the splash screen.

Here is part of my code:

```
 void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  setPathUrlStrategy();
  pageParams = detectPage();
  runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => MenuProvider()),
      ],
      child: const MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      title: 'Otree.pro',
      theme: pageParams.themeData,
      themeMode: ThemeMode.light,
      debugShowMaterialGrid: false,
      checkerboardRasterCacheImages: false,
      showPerformanceOverlay: false,
      checkerboardOffscreenLayers: false,
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      showSemanticsDebugger: false,
      routerConfig: GoRouter(
        routes:
            pageParams.routes, // Set the initial location to the splash page
        // Define your other routes here
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And here is how routes look like now:

```
routes: <RouteBase>[
    GoRoute(
        path: '/',
        name: 'main',
        builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
          return const SplashScreenLogoV5(
            next: '/catalogue',
          );
        },
        routes: [
          GoRoute(
              name: 'catalogue',
              path: 'catalogue',
              builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) =>
                  const HomePage(),
              routes: [
                GoRoute(
                  name: 'home',
                  path: 'home',
                  builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) =>
                      const HomePage(),
                ),
                GoRoute(
                    name: 'portfolio',
                    path: 'portfolio',
                    builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
                      startPage = 1;
                      return const HomePage();
                    }),
                GoRoute(
                    name: 'price',
                    path: 'price',
                    builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
                      startPage = 2;
                      return const HomePage();
                    }),
                GoRoute(
                    name: 'contacts',
                    path: 'contacts',
                    builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
                      startPage = 3;
                      return const HomePage();
                    }),
              ]),
        ]),
  ],
```

Here is the [outcome](https://otree-1557273831467--beta-uxoqrl95.web.app/catalogue/home) that I get. As you see, no Splash screen, page redirects for some reason after several seconds for some reason. And the navigation is not applied yet.

So please help me...